# Implement semantic versioning of Docker images in GitHub Actions workflow and push to ECR

Tags: docker, github-actions, cicd, amazon-ecr

I'm utilizing GitHub Actions to automate the building and pushing of a Docker image to AWS ECR. I've successfully set up a workflow for this process. However, I'm now aiming to implement Semantic Versioning and include two labels on my Docker image: [v.0.0.1] and latest. The desired outcome is a tag like v.0.0.1-latest.

Ideally, with each subsequent push, I intend to increment the version, e.g., v.0.0.2-latest, while the previous image transitions to v.0.0.1 without the latest tag. Despite my attempts using various runners and exploring forums, I've encountered challenges in finding clear explanations or examples. ([this](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/update-major-minor-semver) should probably solve my situation, but is very poor explained)

Could you assist me with a specific and detailed example to achieve this versioning scheme in my GitHub Actions workflow?

```
name: AWS ECR Push

# These permissions are needed to interact with GitHub's OIDC Token endpoint.
permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: read

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "my_branch" ]

env:
  AWS_REGION: "ca-central-1"
  AWS_ACCOUNT_ID: "123456789"
  REPO_NAME: "my_repo"
  IMAGE_TAG: latest

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Clone repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Configure AWS credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v2
      with:
        role-to-assume: arn:aws:iam::${{env.AWS_ACCOUNT_ID }}:role/github-actions-${{ env.REPO_NAME }}
        aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}    
        
    - name: Login to Amazon ECR
      id: login-ecr
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1
      
    - name: Build and push the Docker image to ECR
      env:
        ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
      run: |
        docker build . --file Dockerfile --tag $ECR_REGISTRY/$REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
        docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This resolve the issue:

```
name: AWS ECR Push

# These permissions are needed to interact with GitHub's OIDC Token endpoint.
permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: read

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "my_branch" ]

env:
  AWS_REGION: "ca-central-1"
  AWS_ACCOUNT_ID: "123456789"
  REPO_NAME: "my_repo"
  IMAGE_TAG: latest

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Clone repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Configure AWS credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v2
      with:
        role-to-assume: arn:aws:iam::${{env.AWS_ACCOUNT_ID }}:role/github-actions-${{ env.REPO_NAME }}
        aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}    
        
    - name: Login to Amazon ECR
      id: login-ecr
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

    - name: Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
      id: meta
      uses: docker/metadata-action@v5.5.0
      with:
        images: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}/${{ env.REPO_NAME }}

    - name: Build and push Docker images
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v5.1.0
      with:
        context: .
        file: ./Dockerfile
        push: true
        tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
        labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}
```